# Socket.io client is not working with React Native

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-native, socket.io, expo

I am using socket.io in the backend, it's working fine on the frontend with vanilla javascript using socket.io-client but when I try to connect socket.io through React Native I am getting the error:

Vanilla JS(Working Perfectly fine) :

> ```
>    <script>
>
>     var socket =  io.connect('http://localhost:9092');
>     socket.on('connect', function() {
>       output('<span class="connect-msg">Client has connected to the server!</span>');
>    });
> ```

**React Native code: (Not working)**

> ```
>  this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9092',{ 
>  reconnection: true,
>  reconnectionDelay: 500,
>  jsonp: false,
>  reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
>  transports: ['websocket']});
>
> this.socket.on('connect',function(e){
>   console.log("on Connect");
> })
>
> this.socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
>   console.log(err)
> });
> ```

**Error:**

> websocket error
>
> Stack trace:   node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js:67:22 in
> onError
> node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/websocket.js:157:17 in
> onerror   node_modules/event-target-shim/lib/event-target.js:172:43 in
> dispatchEvent
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/WebSocket.js:290:10 in
>
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:191:12
> in emit
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:349:47
> in __callFunction
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:106:26
> in 
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:297:10
> in __guard
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:105:17
> in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

I am using https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio in the backend.

React Native app has been created using [expo-cli](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/expo-cli/).

Comment: IIRC React Native only allows HTTPS on iOS. You might need to eject and add the App Transport Security exception

Comment: @Li357 Thanks for quick reply. Though I am testing it on Android using expo app.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using localhost try getting an IP
remember the IP on both sides phone and PC should be same but with different ports and this will solve your error probably

this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9092'}

to

this.socket = io.connect('http://192.x.x.x.x:9092'}

Comment: I have the same issue. I even tried with the IP, but it doesn't work.

Comment: please check that you are using same ip on both networks

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I was struggling from hours to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think for mobile you have to use https to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, I was using version 3 of socket.io-client

downgrade your version to 2.1.1 using below command:

`npm i socket.io-client@2.1.1`

This should start working then